# How to develop pear of PHP in C++

Tags: php, c++

I have used PHP a lot , and now i want to give back PHP community some contribution but for this I need help from experts  ,

What i want to know is how to develop PHP pears in C++ or can suggest links or path way for it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: AFAIR, PEAR are modules written in pure PHP. Compiled extensions reside in PECL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to develop an extension module for php in C/C++ take a look at [PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide to the Zend Engine](http://docs.php.net/internals2).
If you have existing C/C++ code you might also be interested in [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/):

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is used with different types of languages including common scripting languages such as Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby.